# Create a 3 model relation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am not sure how to create an event at all time but still keeping data integrite correct.
Here are my models

Customer

```
  id
  first
  last
  email
```

Book

```
  id
  description
```

Book_Manager

```
  customer_id
  book_id
  visible
```

In order to do this I have to use a has_many relationship and his describe has below

```
Book
has_many :book_managers
    has_many :customers, :through => :book_managers
Book_Manager
    belongs_to :customer
    belongs_to :book
Customer
    has_many :book_managers
    has_many :books, :through => :book_managers
```

The idea is to see the data already created from previous time, which mean I would have to create a query where Book = Book_Manager Table where customer_id = current_customer and created_last. I am not to sure how would i create a query like this in the book controllers. I believe it may look like has follow for the query. I am correct? Current customer is the current customer in sessionHelper method

```
@report = BookManager where customer.id == current_customer.id AND created_last.last
```

Last but not least, everytime the customer modify the text by pressing save, The action create would be executed, and create a new book_manager with the correct 3th model books associated with and customer also associated with the book manager.

I have the following code but i am not sure if its correct

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
    def edit
        @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @customer = Customer.first
        @book = @customer.BookManager.build(params[:book])
    end
end
```

Comment: I think you have your relationships backwards. A customer should not belong to a book. I'm not entirely sure of your situation but the way your models look like it seems you want Book_manager belongs_to customer and belongs_to book.

Comment: Also, I' don't think your question is very concrete. Please read over your post and think about what you are asking. You say you want to create a new book_manager with the book_id and book_description yet your models don't seem to have a book_description field?

Comment: Sorry my bad on the customer, will be edited. What i mean by this is to make sure that the third model gets created before creating the second model (book_manager).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Book
  has_many :book_managers
  has_many :books, :through => :book_managers

Book_Manager
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :book

Customer
  has_many :book_managers
  has_many :customers, :through => :book_managers

   Book                Book_Manager          Customer
|-------------|       |-------------|       |---------|
| id          |-1---*-| book_id     |       | id      |
| description |       | customer_id |-*---1-| first   |
|             |       | id          |       | last    |
|             |       |             |       | email   |
|-------------|       |-------------|       |---------|
```

As you have the `have_many through` you don't need to refer the join table (`Book_Manager`). You can access it directly:

```
@customer = Customer.first
@books = @customer.books #return all books
```

Comment: I upvoted primarily for the ASCII illustration of the DB relationships.

Comment: Does it make a difference if i place my through before book_manager alone?

Comment: @Jseb - I don't think it makes any difference, but I like to think that `:through => :book_managers` is only available if you have the `has_many :book_managers`. That's the only reason I put it first...

Comment: So when i create a new book i would have to simply write this @book = @customer.Book.build(params[:book]) and this would create a new book instance and a new book_manager with the correct parameter?

Comment: actually: `@customer.books.build(params[:book])`

Comment: Also is my query that i updated is correct??. And Thank you very much, you help me a lot. Also with linux ubuntu what program would be the best to view the sql statement created? Although i am the terminal

Comment: forget about Book_Manager, you don't need it anymore... the `through` allow you to access book and customer directly. @customer.books.build(params[:book])

Comment: Ok thank you very much sir!! Its still just ackward coming from php, or asp to not really deal with the database that much.

Comment: you query should be: `@report = current_user.books.order("created_at DESC").limit(1)` - it will return the last book related to the current_user

Comment: One little questions, because i wanna see book information, i am doing a partial from the customer to book/form. How would can i see it, i having the following error undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class

1: <%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
2:   <% if @book.errors.any? %>

and i change @report to be @book, but should i place the book in the book controller or on the customer controller

Comment: I didn't really understand what you are trying to do. You mean, you have a partial view related to the customer that you want to access from book? if so, you need to create a shared folder inside view folder and save the partial there... if it is not what you are looking for, please open a new question and include the code so someone can help